# Responsive image with caption and overlay hover effect

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, responsive

[Click here to see Screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKGeU.jpg) I want to create a responsive image with caption and overlay hover effect.

Notes:

- In all devices, on rollover and rollout, caption position will remain same.
- On rollover, caption background will cover the whole image with 60% opacity.
- For aligning the caption and caption background, every 10px-15px I need to write media queries.
- Please see screenshot attached.

```css
.container-home{
 width: 100%;
 background: #e3e3e3;
 padding-bottom: 40px;
 margin-bottom: -20px;
}
.caption-style-2{
  }

 .caption-style-2 .img-home{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 2% 0;
  
 }

 .caption-style-2 .img-home:hover .caption{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(-230px);
  -webkit-transform:translateY(-230px);
  -moz-transform:translateY(-230px);
  -ms-transform:translateY(-230px);
  -o-transform:translateY(-230px);

 }


 .caption-style-2 img{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  float: left;
  z-index: 4;
  width: 100%;
 }


 .caption-style-2 .caption{
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: .8;
  top:70px;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.15s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:all 0.15s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:all 0.15s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition:all 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition:all 0.15s ease-in-out;

 }
 .caption-style-2 .blur{
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  opacity: 0.7;
  height: 400px;
  width: 435px;
  top: 150px;
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
 }

 .caption-style-2 .caption-text h1{
  font-size: 18px;
 }
 .caption-style-2 .caption-text{
  z-index: 10;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 220px;
  left: 15px;
  top:128px;
  opacity: 1;
 }
 .caption-style-2{
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin:auto;
 }
 
 .caption-style-2 .col-md-4, .caption-style-2 .col-sm-6, .caption-style-2 .col-xs-6{
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
 }
 
 .caption-style-2 .margin-a {
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-right: 2%;
 } 
 
 .caption-style-2 .margin-b {
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-right: 2%;
 }
 
 .caption-style-2 .col-xs-6 {
  width: 48%;
  
 } 
 .caption-style-2 .sky-blue-bg {
  background: #0086b8;
 }
```

```html
<div class="row caption-style-2">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 img-home">
    <img src="images/image_1.png" alt="">
    <div class="caption">
      <div class="blur sky-blue-bg"></div>
      <div class="caption-text">
        <h1>Caption 1</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. You must at least attempt to code this yourself. If you have any particular issue, then you can come back **with your code** and ask a more specific question then.

Comment: Also, no screenshot attached..

Comment: Added screenshot, HTML and CSS

Answer (score 1):

I'm so sorry fellow coders. I'm really bored so, did you want something like this?

```css
body {
  margin: 15px;
}

.img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}

.img-wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.img-wrapper .caption {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: rgba(239, 169, 103, 0.85);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .15s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .15s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .15s ease-in-out;
}

.img-wrapper:hover .caption {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-wrapper">
     <img src="http://thumb101.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/1248838/282506297/stock-vector-cartoon-carousel-with-colorful-horses-282506297.jpg" />
     <div class="caption">
       Lorem ipsum dolor
     </div>
</div>
```